# min value in the stack

Tags: c, data-structures

i'm trying to get the min value in the stack which StackMin, Pop and Push which are all `Θ(1)`.
my code doesn't work...here's my try :

```
typedef struct{
    int top;
    int entry[1000];
    int small;
} Stack;

void Pop(int *e,Stack *ps){
    *e=ps->entry[--ps->top];
}

void Push(int e,Stack *ps){
    ps->entry[ps->top++]=e;
}

int StackMin(Stack *ps){
    ps->small=ps->entry[ps->top];
    while(!StackEmpty(ps)){
        int *e;
        *e=ps->entry[--ps->top];
        if(ps->small >= *e){
            ps->small = *e;
        }
    }
    return ps->small;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the compiler give you errors? You'll have to give more information than this.

Comment: "small" accesses uninitialized memory, you're off by one.

Comment: Push, pop, and Min cannot all be of `Theta(1)`, unless you're talking about a historical min. If you store a min value, you can get `O(1)` on push and StackMin, but if you pop a value equal to the min you're going to have to recalculate the min - a linear operation.  You could store the array sorted, making Min calculation `O(1)`, but push and pop `O(n)` - you could store it sorted, but with a stack that has references to the array values, making push, pop and min all appear to be `O(1)`, but since push and pop violate the sorted storage, they would actually be `O(n)` as you repair the damage.

Comment: FrankieTheKneeMan Could you explain me what is exactly the meaning of Θ(1). above ?!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two stacks to do this. One stack can have min values in the order and every time you call min value you update this stack. Try to figure out the algorithm on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a pointer in these lines:

```
int *e; 
*e=ps->entry[--ps->top]; 
if(ps->small >= *e){ 
    ps->small = *e; 
}
```

Change them to:

```
int e = ps->entry[--ps->top]; 
if(ps->small >= e){ 
    ps->small = e; 
}
```

Comment: Reached 1000!!!! Vote me up people, get me to 2000 :)

Answer (score 1):

"doesn't work" isn't that helpful a description...  But in any case, this looks problematic:

```
int *e;
*e=ps->entry[--ps->top];
if(ps->small >= *e){
    ps->small = *e;
}
```

The thing is, you have declared a pointer (which currently points at nothing - it is uninitialised), and then you write a value to the (invalid) location it points to.

If by chance the code doesn't crash, and your question is about the algorithm, another user has posted an answer about that.